# Edit .svg to animate - XML

Tags: css, xml, animation, svg

Can somebody help me to properly rotate the disk of this image ?
I have tried somethig ( if you run the code ), but whithout succes. But there is a beating of the disk
It should look like this: https://mensis.ro/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Logo-Doors.gif

```
<animateTransform attributeName="transform"
attributeType="XML"
type="rotate"
from="0 50 50"
to="360 50 50"
dur="10s"
repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

Full code: https://pastebin.com/d7Ur54ZB

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prevent disc beating, it is necessary to correctly indicate the center of rotation.
CSS rule helps you do this: [transform-box: fill-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box)

Add to your application:

```
#disk{
    transform-origin: center center;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    animation: rotate_disk 10s linear forwards infinite;
  }

  @keyframes rotate_disk {
    100% {
        transform: rotateZ(360deg);
    }
  }
```

---

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/Alexandr_T/pen/wvBoxKV)

---

Answer (score 1):

In order not to mix two different solutions and facilitate the choice of one of them, this option is drawn up as a separate topic.
In the first solution, the bitmaps were converted to base64 format. There is no gain from this solution since SVG in this case behaves like a normal raster image.
But the file size turned out to be very large - **132k** therefore it is inconvenient to read and edit it.

**Consider a solution for animating bitmap images.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Raster images can be added inside SVG using the `<image>` tag

And use the usual `CSS` rules for animation

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="499.968" height="281.232" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
<defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        opacity: 0.96;
      }
  #disk{
 transform-origin: center center;
 transform-box: fill-box;
 animation: rotate_disk 10s linear forwards infinite;
  }

  @keyframes rotate_disk {
   100% {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
   }
  }
   
    </style>
  </defs>
<image x="293" y="75" width="1255" height="959" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/34irD.png"/>

<image id="disk" class="cls-1" x="515" y="165" width="815" height="815" xlink:href=" https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qas6q.png"/> 

<image id="scris" class="cls-1" x="363" y="740" width="1105" height="233" xlink:href=" https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCbha.png"/>
</svg>
```

In this embodiment, the file size is **824 bytes**